# Drawable RippleEffectColor Errorl

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-drawable

["@color/rippleEffectColor" Error in Red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMu1U.png)

App>Res>Values>Colors.xml
- I have created color for RippleEffectColor

```
<resources>
     <Color name="rippleEffectColor">#F816A463</Color>
</resources>

App>Res>Drawable
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    **android:color="@color/rippleEffectColor"**
    tools:targetApi="lollipop"
    >
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
           <solid android:color="@color/btnSignIn"></solid>
           <stroke android:color="color/btnSignIn" android:width="2dp"></stroke>
           <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
       </shape>
    </item>

</ripple>
```

But I keep having an error on ***android:color="@color/rippleEffectColor"***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two typos in your code.
I ran it like this, it's working:

```
<resources>
     // color has to be lower case
     <color name="rippleEffectColor">#F816A463</color> 
</resources>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:color="@color/rippleEffectColor"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop"
    >
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
           <solid android:color="@color/btnSignIn"></solid>

           //The @ sign was missing before color
           <stroke android:color="@color/btnSignIn" android:width="2dp"></stroke>
           <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
       </shape>
    </item>

</ripple>
```

Comment: yes effectivily, i just catch that error..  thanks for that! i will keep in mind...